# Does the Spotify API stream advertisements as well

Tags: spotify, libspotify

I am developing an Application which has a feature for searching and playing a song from spotify using the Spotify API. This is my first time using this API and wanted to know would the user (who is listening to the song) hear an audio advertisement, the same way we hear ads on the spotify desktop free account or he can listen to any number of songs without any ads.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, libspotify applications will not have adverts played, and libspotify doesn't support advertisements at all. However, because of this, only Spotify Premium users can log into an application using libspotify.